# Export/Test Movie Issues

Tags: flash, air, export, flash-cs5.5

I'm developing a game on AIR for smartpones and since a few days I have the following problem:

when I hit ctrl + return to test my movie, it won't open and will endless export (the progress bar opens and increases to 100% and this status is for hours). Flash won't create a swf file for me. When I hit publish, my flash crashes completely.

I don't get any error messages.

What I tested so far:

- activated/deactivated movie compression
- activated/deactivated xmp-metadata
- Changed rendermode (without, direct, gpu)
- activated/deactivated jpeg-deblocking
- deleted app.xml file
- increased publish cache size

The only way that the export/publishing works is when I delete elements from my library. But I need the elements. I got 701 elements so far and I need more.

Maybe someone can please help me.

**EDIT:** It's AIR 3.2

**EDIT2:**

- Changed save location
- Changed player in publish settings (AIR for Android, AIR 2.6, AIR for iOS, Flash Player 10.2)
- Moved all files to different/new folder

**EDIT3:**
I think it's a problem with the bitmaps. Everytime I restart the fla-file other image previews can't be displayed and when I try to reload the image into the library, flash crashes.

I saved my images again and imported them again, same issue. Sometimes the preview will be displayed and sometimes not.

And when I look through my bitmaps and there are all previews available, flash stops exporting when the RAM usage is at 1,3 GB

**And EDIT4 :D**

Now I deleted some bitmaps again and it launches the ADL now. But what is the problem with my bitmaps? In Photoshop I hit "save for web" and my other images are not corrupted, but only those "sets" (level 5 and level 6 every time). They are saved as jpg, RGB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Flash hates much elements in library (or huge filesizes).

After deleting some images from my library and used code to edit/transform/change them in game the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is not related with AIR yet as you are still in the CS5 compiling process. I remember I have encountered a similar situation( not as serious as you though), it is caused by the font I used, when I try to compile, the compiler try to package all fonts I used in those library elements into the SWF file, that cost time and space of course, so the solution for me under that case is simply raster all characters I used special font.

Not sure if this is the case for you. but if you use fonts in vector resources, try to rasterize them. that might helps.

Comment: No, I think that's not the problem, when you take a look at EDIT3 and 4 from my question. But another question: how do I rasterize the font?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem and discovered that it crashes because there is a tween that is only 1 frame but has an ease in or out attached to it.  If I go through and remove all tweens that are only 1 frame, everything works great!

Removing items from your library may have worked simply because one of those items was a movie with the single frame tween problem.